# Airflow always loading the same connection in Airflow localhost

Tags: airflow

When I open a Admin > Connections > Some connection it always show the same connection, even opening other connections, how could I solve that?

I can see on Network Tab the correct request (I think it's correct):

> http://localhost:8080/admin/connection/edit/?id={id_changes_for_each_connection}&url=%2Fadmin%2Fconnection%2F

But it loads the correct and then load other connection (the same incorrect connection)

Airflow version: 1.10.4

Comment: can you add which version of airflow you are running and maybe add a picture to better explain what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is use the browser (Google Chrome) in anonymous, then I would guess it's some kind of cache of the browser.